# Como usar arrays em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, exceção

É uma pergunta bem iniciante (sou novo em Java, vim do C++). Tenho que fazer um programa que pega 4 notas de 10 alunos, mas quando vou mexer com os "ponteiros" (arrays), o meu programa devolve uma exception:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Aluno
{
    public int[] nota;
}

class Nota
{
    private Aluno[] aluno;
    private int totalAlunos;
    private int NumeroNotas;
    public Nota(int numero_alunos, int numero_notas)
    {
        this.totalAlunos = numero_alunos;
        this.NumeroNotas = numero_notas;
        this.aluno = new Aluno[numero_alunos];
        for(int i = 0; i < totalAlunos; i++)
        {
            this.aluno = new Aluno[numero_notas];
        }
        for(int numero_de_alunos = 0; numero_de_alunos < numero_alunos; numero_de_alunos++)
        {
            System.out.print("Aluno " + (numero_de_alunos+1) + ":\n");
            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i = 0; i < NumeroNotas; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Digite a nota número " + (i+1) + ": ");
                this.aluno[numero_de_alunos].nota[i] = Scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    public int PegarMedia(int NumeroAluno)
    {
        int stack = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < NumeroNotas; i++)
        {
            stack += this.aluno[NumeroAluno].nota[i];
        }
        return stack / NumeroNotas;

    }
    public void MostrarMedia()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < totalAlunos; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Media do aluno " + i + ":");
            System.out.print(PegarMedia(i) + "\n");
        }
     System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
//Fim das classes

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Nota notas = new Nota(10,4);
        notas.MostrarMedia();
    }
}
```

Devolve:

> run: Aluno 1: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException Digite a nota número 1:    at
>   Nota.(Test.java:28)     at Test.main(Test.java:59) Java Result: 1

O que eu estou fazendo errado? O que eu devo fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instanciar um array de objetos não implica em instanciar cada um de seus elementos. Por isso dá `NullPointerException` quando você tenta acessar `aluno[numero_de_alunos]`.

Já no caso de `nota[i]` isso não acontece porque trata-se de um array de `int`, que é um tipo primitivo, MAS você tem que instanciar o array de qualquer forma, ou terá mais uma exception para tratar em seguida.

Você pode fazer as duas coisas no próprio laço `for`:

```
this.aluno = new Aluno[numero_alunos];

for(int i = 0; i < totalAlunos; i++)
{
    this.aluno[i] = new Aluno();
    aluno[i].nota = new int[numero_notas];
}
```

Comment: Obrigado :) Cometi uma gafe, fiz o contrário. Mas agora, depois de colocar todos os números, eu recebo: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at Nota.<init>(Test.java:28)
 at Test.main(Test.java:59)
Java Result: 1`. E no ideone, dá outros: https://ideone.com/mrilal

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, confira aí.

Answer (score 3):

Para criar o Array basta fazer assim:
`ArrayList<Aluno>  listaDeAlunos;
//ArrayList<DoTipoDaClasse> nomeDaLista;`

Depois você irá instanciar:

```
listaDeAlunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>(numero_notas);
//numero_de_notas será o tamanho da lista.
```

Depois para incluir notas em cada posição, faça a substituição abaixo no 2° for:

```
//this.aluno[numero_de_alunos].nota[i] = Scan.nextInt();
listaDeAlunos.add(Scan.nextInt());
```

Para pegar cada nota para a média:

```
//stack += this.aluno[NumeroAluno].nota[i];
stack += listaDeAlunos.get(i);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa, um pouco complicado pra mim, hahaha

Comment: ArrayList é uma classe e facilita no entendimento, já que ele já possui métodos add, get, remove.
Se for usar deverá importá-la:
import java.util.ArrayList;